# start /wait fails to wait if file already open

Tags: ruby, windows, batch-file

```
system( "start /wait file.docx")
```

This starts the file but **fails to wait if another docx file already open**. Works perfectly if there is no file open.

What I am trying to do : I would like to open a file in windows with its default editor and wait for the user to input and do some changes to the file post save, hence I am using

```
/wait.
```

Thanks for any tip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour in winword is to reuse existing instances of the executable to open multiple documents. So, the second open file operation delegates its work into the existing one and exits, so the start command returns.

One usual option is to use COM to open the file and test for closing of the instance. But i know nothing of ruby or if it supports COM.

The best approach will be locate the winword executable and call it directly using as paramenters `/w filename.docx` to force opening the file into a new instance.

Comment: I tried the second approach to open the winword executable by doing this : start "" /w "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE"
What is the syntax to put the filename.docx in the above command

Comment: @Ross `start "" /wait "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE" /w "filename.docx"` The `/w` switch is not the `/wait` switch of the start command. It is a switch to the winword executable telling it to open a new instance. If you have a new instance then you can wait for it to finish

Comment: I am not able to do the same for EXCEL.EXE and POWERPNT.EXE
it asks me for file download when I run like this:
start "" /wait "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\EXCEL.EXE" /w "Test\test2.xlsx"
Note: test1.xlsx is already open

Comment: @Ross, `/w` is one of the switches winword can handle. Excel and PowerPoint have their own specific switches (and some shared with winword). In this case, both for excel and powerpoint, the office documentation does not include any switch to force the creation of a new instance. Maybe, as you have test, it is not needed and it is the default behaviour.

Comment: /w should be removed then it works for excel but not powerpoint

Comment: @Ross, some time ago i answered a question not about opening, but closing excel ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19657586/2861476) for reference). Not only each of the programs in office behaves differently, the creation of a new process or reuse of a existing one depends on the way to start the program. And i'm not sure it will be 100% stable across versions. So, maybe, at last you will have to deal with the COM interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I can get both word and excel to work but powerpoint is not working. It doesn't wait if an instance already open, and it works fine if instance not open. I checked the switches for ppt but found nothing related to opening in the new instance. Can you please help

Comment: @Ross, sorry, i don't know ruby enough to help. I can suggest [this](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com.es/2008/08/automating-powerpoint-with-ruby.html) as a start point. Open the file and bind to active document events of keep checking for document close to know when the work has been done. As far as i know, the only other way to do it is to force open of powerpoint under another account so it gets open in a separate process.